# C# handlebars error in Handlebars.Compile() function

Tags: c#, uwp, handlebars.net

I am trying to use handlebars with C# in universal windows platform (UWP) using Handlebars.Net in this GitHub link (https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net)

I used simple code used in the usage section in the link above and even though it didn't work always stop at `handlebars.compile()` function and throws error.

My code is a very basic simple one just when I press a button in the application, I enter debug mode to see the result but I got this exception message.

This is the error message.

[image: error message]

[image: full exception error]

and this is the code I used.

```
    try
    {
        string source = "{{title}} and This Is body : {{body}}";

        var template = Handlebars.Compile(source);

        var data = new
        {
            title = "My new post",
            body = "This is my first post!"
        };

        var result = template(data);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
```

I tried installing Linq express and Linq itself but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars.Net uses [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/#:%7E:text=Expression%20Trees%20%28C%23%29%20Expression%20trees%20represent%20code%20in,a%20binary%20operation%20such%20as%20x%20%3C%20y.) to compile templates.
`MissingMethodException` means that platform you're trying to compile the template on does not support required Expression Trees features. It's known issue on iOS. I may assume that the same might be true for UWP.

Comment: thanks a lot,  i decide to make canvas drawing  fixed